# Is "悪くならない” an okay replacement for "日持ち”?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Would "悪くならない” be used correctly if we're referring to food and how it won't go bad as fast because of preservatives and can it be used instead of using "日持ち”? I know that "warukunaranai" means "it won't go bad" or "it won't turn bad" but is it an appropriate replacement?

For better context, we saw a video in class about food additives and we were righting down pros and cons of food preservatives, and for one of the pros the teacher typed "悪くならない（保存料）”　"warukunaranai (hozonryou)".

Comment: I would think 腐らない would be more appropriate for food.

Answer (score 5):

Using 悪くならない for food is a stable choice that means "don't spoil". But just in case, it is not an *exact* replacement for 日持ち, as the word is a noun "capacity of lasting long" (no derived verb or adjective usage). What replaces 悪くならない as a whole is 日持ちが良い or 日持ち（が）する.

悪くならない保存料 would mean "preservative that doesn't let (food) spoil". It may sound weird, but is a basic grammatical mechanism in Japanese often referred to as こんにゃく文: comes from the typical example こんにゃくは太らない "Konjak doesn't **cause you to** gain weight" (not "konjak doesn't gain weight").